# how to use zapier in node js

Tags: node.js, web, webautomation, react-fullstack

good day everyone,I'm currently working on integrating a zap into my Node.js app to achieve web automation. I've been searching for a guide or solution to help me with this task, but unfortunately, I haven't been successful in finding one so far. If anyone here has any recommendations, guides, or solutions that could assist me in integrating a zap into my Node.js app, I would greatly appreciate your help. I also attempted to use Huginn, but I faced challenges when trying to add it to my Node.js environment. Any suggestions or insights would be highly valuable. Thank you in advance for your assistance!